# How to merge HCSR04 code with DF Player mini mp3

Tags: arduino-uno

As the title says, I have a problem to merging the HCSR04 code with DF Player mini mp3 codebases so that they are working together in the one sketch.

The idea is when the ultrasonic sensor reads a certain range, it will trigger a specific mp3 files via the DF player.

I'm using 5 Ultrasonic sensors, and I wanted each sensors to trigger different mp3 files.

***Ultrasonic code:***

```
int trigPin1=2;
int echoPin1=3;

int trigPin2=4;
int echoPin2=5;

int trigPin3=6;
int echoPin3=7;

int trigPin4=8;
int echoPin4=9;

int trigPin5=10;
int echoPin5=11;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(trigPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin1, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin3, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin4, INPUT);
  pinMode(trigPin5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin5, INPUT);

}

void loop() {
  long duration1, distance1;
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, LOW);  // Added this line
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(15); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin1, LOW);
  duration1 = pulseIn(echoPin1, HIGH);
  distance1 = duration1/58;

long duration2, distance2;
  digitalWrite(trigPin2, LOW);  // Added this line
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin2, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(15); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin2, LOW);
  duration2 = pulseIn(echoPin2, HIGH);
  distance2= duration2/58;

long duration3, distance3;
  digitalWrite(trigPin3, LOW);  // Added this line
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin3, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(15); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin3, LOW);
  duration3 = pulseIn(echoPin3, HIGH);
  distance3= duration3/58;

  long duration4, distance4;
  digitalWrite(trigPin4, LOW);  // Added this line
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin4, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(15); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin4, LOW);
  duration4 = pulseIn(echoPin4, HIGH);
  distance4= duration4/58;

  long duration5, distance5;
  digitalWrite(trigPin5, LOW);  // Added this line
  delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin5, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(15); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(trigPin5, LOW);
  duration5 = pulseIn(echoPin5, HIGH);
  distance5= duration5/58;


  Serial.print (distance1);
  Serial.print (",");
  Serial.print(distance2);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(distance3);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(distance4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(distance5);
  Serial.println(",");
  delay(100);

}
```

***DF Player code:***

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h"

SoftwareSerial mySoftwareSerial(12, 13); // RX, TX
DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;
void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value);

void setup()
{
  mySoftwareSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("DFRobot DFPlayer Mini Demo"));
  Serial.println(F("Initializing DFPlayer ... (May take 3~5 seconds)"));

  if (!myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial)) {  //Use softwareSerial to communicate with mp3.
    Serial.println(F("Unable to begin:"));
    Serial.println(F("1.Please recheck the connection!"));
    Serial.println(F("2.Please insert the SD card!"));
    while(true);
  }
  Serial.println(F("DFPlayer Mini online."));

  myDFPlayer.volume(10);  //Set volume value. From 0 to 30
}

void loop()
{
  static unsigned long timer = millis();

  if (millis() - timer > 2000) {
    timer = millis();
    myDFPlayer.next();  //Play next mp3 every 3 second.
  }

  if (myDFPlayer.available()) {
    printDetail(myDFPlayer.readType(), myDFPlayer.read()); //Print the detail message from DFPlayer to handle different errors and states.
  }
}

void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value){
  switch (type) {
    case TimeOut:
      Serial.println(F("Time Out!"));
      break;
    case WrongStack:
      Serial.println(F("Stack Wrong!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardInserted:
      Serial.println(F("Card Inserted!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardRemoved:
      Serial.println(F("Card Removed!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardOnline:
      Serial.println(F("Card Online!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerPlayFinished:
      Serial.print(F("Number:"));
      Serial.print(value);
      Serial.println(F(" Play Finished!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerError:
      Serial.print(F("DFPlayerError:"));
      switch (value) {
        case Busy:
          Serial.println(F("Card not found"));
          break;
        case Sleeping:
          Serial.println(F("Sleeping"));
          break;
        case SerialWrongStack:
          Serial.println(F("Get Wrong Stack"));
          break;
        case CheckSumNotMatch:
          Serial.println(F("Check Sum Not Match"));
          break;
        case FileIndexOut:
          Serial.println(F("File Index Out of Bound"));
          break;
        case FileMismatch:
          Serial.println(F("Cannot Find File"));
          break;
        case Advertise:
          Serial.println(F("In Advertise"));
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: How to merge these 2 codes, I tried many ways but can find the right one, i'm literally new to writing codes like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored it a bit, to remove the need to repeat the same code, 5 times, for 5 sensors.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"

#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h"


const byte SENSOR_COUNT = 5;
byte triggerPins[SENSOR_COUNT] = {2,4,6,8,10};
byte echoPins[SENSOR_COUNT]    = {3,5,7,9,11};


SoftwareSerial mySoftwareSerial(12, 13); // RX, TX

DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;

void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value);

void setup()
{
  mySoftwareSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  for( byte i=0; i<SENSOR_COUNT; i++ )
  {
    pinMode(triggerPins[i], OUTPUT);
    pinMode(echoPins[i], INPUT);
  }

  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("DFRobot DFPlayer Mini Demo"));
  Serial.println(F("Initializing DFPlayer ... (May take 3~5 seconds)"));

  if (!myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial)) {  //Use softwareSerial to communicate with mp3.
    Serial.println(F("Unable to begin:"));
    Serial.println(F("1.Please recheck the connection!"));
    Serial.println(F("2.Please insert the SD card!"));
    while(true);
  }
  Serial.println(F("DFPlayer Mini online."));

  myDFPlayer.volume(10);  //Set volume value. From 0 to 30

}

int currentSound = -1;
void loop()
{

  for( byte i=0; i<SENSOR_COUNT; i++ ) // loop through all distance sensors
  {
    if( detectPresence(i) ) // check if there is an object near it
    {
      if(currentSound!=i) // check that it's a different sensor than the one that was last triggered
      {
        Serial.print("play song number ");
        Serial.println(i);
        myDFPlayer.play(i+1); // play song nr `i+1`
      }
      currentSound = i;
    }
  }


  if (myDFPlayer.available()) {
    printDetail(myDFPlayer.readType(), myDFPlayer.read()); //Print the detail message from DFPlayer to handle different errors and states.
  }

}

// detectPresence will return TRUE if there is an object close to it.
bool detectPresence(byte sensorNr)
{
  if( sensorNr>=SENSOR_COUNT )
    return false;
  long duration, distance;
  //digitalWrite(triggerPins[sensorNr], LOW);  // Added this line
  //delayMicroseconds(10); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(triggerPins[sensorNr], HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(15); // Added this line
  digitalWrite(triggerPins[sensorNr], LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPins[sensorNr], HIGH);
  distance = duration/58;

  return distance<30;// choose your own value here, from which distance it should trigger a sound
}

void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value){

  switch (type) {
    case TimeOut:
      Serial.println(F("Time Out!"));
      break;
    case WrongStack:
      Serial.println(F("Stack Wrong!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardInserted:
      Serial.println(F("Card Inserted!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardRemoved:
      Serial.println(F("Card Removed!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardOnline:
      Serial.println(F("Card Online!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerPlayFinished:
      Serial.print(F("Number:"));
      Serial.print(value);
      Serial.println(F(" Play Finished!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerError:
      Serial.print(F("DFPlayerError:"));
      switch (value) {
        case Busy:
          Serial.println(F("Card not found"));
          break;
        case Sleeping:
          Serial.println(F("Sleeping"));
          break;
        case SerialWrongStack:
          Serial.println(F("Get Wrong Stack"));
          break;
        case CheckSumNotMatch:
          Serial.println(F("Check Sum Not Match"));
          break;
        case FileIndexOut:
          Serial.println(F("File Index Out of Bound"));
          break;
        case FileMismatch:
          Serial.println(F("Cannot Find File"));
          break;
        case Advertise:
          Serial.println(F("In Advertise"));
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gerben! this works absolutely perfect, buy yet there is one last problem, sensor #1 now trigger mp3 player to play "song #0", how do i switch it so sensor #1 plays song #1, sensor #2 plays song #2 and so on? thank you for all your help man! appreciate it much!

Comment: It should already do that! Doesn't it? There is only a problem if multiple sensors are triggering at the same time.

Comment: From what i'm seen and heard, when sensor#1 triggered it plays song#0 and its not playing anything since the DFPlayer files start with 1, not 0, or something, correct me if i'm wrong but it does plays song#0, and nothing come out, and the first file on my mp3 list played when sensor#2 triggered. so it become Sensor#1 Plays Song#0, Sensor#2 plays Song#1... Sensor#5 plays Song#4

Comment: I've changed `myDFPlayer.play(i);` to `myDFPlayer.play(i+1);` in the code above. That should fix that.